# flex NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS exists?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

i am trying to run a source that i downloaded in Flex Builder 3
but i get some errors:

like on this line:

```
sendStream = new NetStream(nc,NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
```

Access of possibly undefined property DIRECT_CONNECTIONS through a reference with static type Class.

and here

```
myPeerID = nc.nearID;
```

//nc is NetConnection
and code completion also doesn't show me the nearID property of the NetConnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS s part of flex 4 and is not available in flex 3.

check:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/gumbo/langref/flash/net/NetStream.html#DIRECT_CONNECTIONS

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the Required Flash player version to 10. If you are using Flex Builder 3 you can set this in the Flex Compiler properties for your project.